# Relationship Loop in database design

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

I am trying to design a database schema and I have a question im my mind. In my database I have three table (Table(A|B|C)) and TableC refers TableB, Table B refers Table A and Table C refers Table B (C -> B -> A and C -> A).

What I want to know first is, can I consider this a loop and if it is loops are killer or not for DB design (when I consider a directed graph its not, but what about DB design)? Also, is it possible to have loops for a 3NF normalized database?

Moreover, I just want to delete the related rows from Tables B and C when a referenced value is deleted from Table A. Although Table C reference Table B, I do not have a UPDATE/DELETE constraint for this foreign key. Whenever, a row deleted/updated from/on Table A, all related rows in Table B/C should be effected. Is that suitable for referential integrity in terms of not to create multiple paths during cascaded operations from one table to another?

There are good books which had been discusses widely, but still I would be glad if you can recommend good resources about this kind of tips/tricks and practical information.

Answer (score 0):

If these relationships are enforced by Foreign Keys. If they are and none of the references are nullable, then you have a problem:

You cannot insert into table C because table B is empty so the non-nullable FK constraint will be broken. Similarly, you cannot insert into table B because A is empty, and you cannot insert into table A because C is empty. This is a killer.

However, if one of there relationships is nullable then you can insert into at least one of the tables, and thus into the others.

Dependency Cycles can be a problem, but they do exist. Dependency Cycles where each dependency in the cycle is non-nullable are always a problem, and I've never actually come across a legitimate example of one.

When deleting/updating the referenced row of an FK relationship, either put on Cascading, force updates/deletes by a BEFORE Trigger, or just let the DBMS throw an error and disallow the action.